# SharePoint Online Conversation yammer feed webpart is throwing Out of stack space error in IE

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, web-parts, yammer

The OOB conversation webpart to display yammer feeds is throwing "Out of stack space" exception in SharePoint Online site in IE11. Any help to fix this issue is very much appreciated.

Regards,
sj

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue. Webpart works in chrome and modern browsers. Not working in IE. Time to move to modern browsers

Comment: Yeah, we need to move to modern browsers. But, unfortunately we need to support IE11 in this scenario. Do you have ADFS integration with your site?